# Recharts graph components positioning over other components

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css, web-frontend, recharts

I am working on creating a dashboard and used Rechart to create graph but now as I am working on making a popup my Rechart components are overlapping over the popup component. Main problem is overlapping of graph components with popup.

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fhjx.png)

This is my approach

Graph

```
<section className="flex-1 h-[360px] px-[40px] py-[30px] bg-white rounded-[20px]">
      <h1 className="text-[20px] font-bold">Activities</h1>
      <h1 className="text-[14px] font-normal text-[#858585] mb-[30px]">May - June 2021</h1>
      <ResponsiveContainer width={'100%'} aspect={5}>
        <BarChart
            data={prodData}
            margin={{
                top: 5,
                right: 30,
                left: 20,
                bottom: 5
            }}
        >
            <Bar dataKey="price" fill="#98D89E" radius={4} barSize={38}/>
            <Bar dataKey="stock" fill="#EE8484" radius={4} barSize={38}/>
            <XAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} dataKey="brand" />
            <CartesianGrid vertical={false}/>
            <YAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend verticalAlign="top" align="right" iconType="circle" iconSize={10}/>
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </section>
```

Popup

```
<section className='fixed top-[25%] left-[35%]'>
            <div className='flex flex-col w-[544px] h-[553px] rounded-[18px] bg-white'>
                <div className='flex flex-row justify-between px-[24px] py-[16px]'>
                    <h1 className='font-semibold text-[20px]'>Add New Profile</h1>
                    <button>
                        <Image 
                            src={Cross} 
                            alt='cross'
                            className='w-[24px]'
                            onClick={handleClick}
                        />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div className='flex flex-row justify-center space-x-20 px-[24px] py-[16px]'>
                    <button>Basic</button>
                    <button>Contact</button>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className='flex flex-col px-[24px] py-[16px]'>
                        <label htmlFor='email' className='mb-[8px]'>Email address</label>
                        <input
                            id='email'
                            type='email'
                            name='email'
                            className='p-4 w-auto h-[40px] rounded-xl bg-[#F5F5F5] mb-5'
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            value={formik.values.email}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor='password' className='mb-[8px]'>Password</label>
                        <input
                            id='password'
                            type='password'
                            name='password'
                            className='p-4 w-auto h-[40px] rounded-xl bg-[#EAEAEA] mb-5 font-bold'
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            value={formik.values.password}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <div className='flex justify-end px-[24px] py-[16px]'>
                        <button className='bg-black text-white font-bold p-2 rounded-lg h-[40px]'>Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I expected this any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGtj.png)